# How to get Customers id through company name

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

Here is my code.

```
 $user_dataaa = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('company',$row[3])->getData();
 echo '<pre>';print_r($user_dataaa);echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assume company is unique? I am not sure about that, if that's not the case you can try something like this, while **$company** is the company name

```
$customerAddresses = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection();
$customerAddresses->addAttributeToSelect('company');
$customerAddresses->addAttributeToFilter('company', array('like' => '%' . $company . '%'));
foreach ($customerAddresses as $customerAddress){
    print_r($customerAddress->getCustomerId());
}
```

You can change the `like` statement for an equal if you are sure **$company** contains the exact value

```
$customerAddresses->addAttributeToFilter('company', array('eq' => $company));
```

**UPDATE**

My mistake, as `company` is a customer address attribute, not a direct customer attribute. Check above updated code, you'd consider sometimes `customer_id` could be null, if address is not associated to any customer

Comment: thanks for answer.I know company name is not unique but i have  only company name to get the details of the customers.

Comment: and now i got this error after using your code => Invalid attribute name: company

Comment: I have edited the answer

Comment: Its Working....You Rocks man :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Get first customer id:**

```
$companyName = "CCC";
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('company')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('company', array('eq' => $companyName));

if($collection->getSize()) {
    $address = $collection->getFirstItem();
    echo $address->getCustomerId();

}
```

**OR**

**Get all customers id:**

```
$companyName = "CCC";
$collection = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('company')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('company', array('eq' => $companyName));

if($collection->getSize()) {
    foreach($collection as $address) {
        echo $address->getCustomerId();    
    }   
}
```

Comment: i got this error "Invalid attribute name: company".

Comment: update ans pls check now